# Using Svn External in the ant script

Tags: svn, ant

My project has properties for the `svn:externals` but to get it working I have to `svn update` the whole project to get the latest jars from the repository.

Now I have build script and would like to get the `svn:externals` in the build script.

I have used svn commands in the build before but don't know how to use `svn:externals` in it .

Could any one help me on this ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you update from the ant script svn:externals will behave exactly the same way.

Comment: Dude that is my question. How do you use svn:externals in the ant script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svn property [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) does not need any special handling. Whenever you call update those externals will be retrieved.

To call `svn update` from ant you need a svn library for it.

[Svnant](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/introduction.html) for example offers nearly all [svn commands as ant tasks](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html)

### Setup

```
      <path id="path.svnant">
          <pathelement location="SVN_ANT_DIR/svnant.jar"/>
          <pathelement location="SVN_ANT_DIR/svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
          <!-- ... -->
      </path>

      <typedef 
          resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" 
          classpathref="path.svnant"
      />
```

### Update Example

```
 <svn javahl="${javahl}">
    <update dir="DIRECTORY_TO_UPDATE" />
 </svn>
```